# unable to populate field on each instance of div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the below code which i'm unable to populate the total field in each individual row of elements.

So each field dynamically inserted will have the same fields, i just need to calculate the fields within that row only.

Here is the jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/glennmartin/3TnyR/

```
var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      var rate = parseInt($(object).children('.rate').val(), 10);
      // var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      var hours =parseInt($(object).children('.hours').val(), 10);
      this.total = Number(rate.val()) * Number(hours.val());
      this.updateTotal(object);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().attr('value', this.total)
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.hours').on("click", function() {
   jQuery.each($('.labouritems'), function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(value);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code working:

```
var LabourItems = {
   rate: null,
   hours: null,
   total: null,
   init: function(object) {
      this.rate = parseInt($(object).children('.rate').first().val(), 10);
      // var rate = $(object).children('.rate').first();
      this.hours =parseInt($(object).children('.hours').first().val(), 10);
      this.total = this.rate * this.hours;
      this.updateTotal(object);
   },
   updateTotal: function(object) {
      $(object).children('.total').first().val(this.total || 0);
   }
}

//reactTochange for those inputs that you want to observe
$('.labouritems input').on("keyup", function() {
   $('.labouritems').each( function(key,value){
      LabourItems.init(this);
   });
});
```

Here's some comments about the changes I've made:

- In your `init` function you were using `var` to assing to variables that you've declared in the context of your object, so I've replaced `var rate` and `var hours` with `this.rate` and `this.hours`
- In your `$(object).children('.rate')` and `$(object).children('.hours')` calls you needed to use `.first()` function to get the first element selected. This is because you are selecting by a class name which there may be more than one of (even if there isn't you'll find you'll still be returned with an array)
- `$(object).children('.total').first().val(this.total || 0);`: You can use `val()` to assign just like you have used it to retrieve the value, elsewhere. `this.total` returns `NaN` when the textbox is empty so `|| 0` ensures that if `NaN` ever appears (it is falsy) then 0 will be used instead (remove it and see what happens if you're curious)
- Made sense that you'd want changes on a keyboard event so I've made your code use the `keydown` event. Of course, you can change this to anything you like.
- When assigning to `this.total` you were using `Number()` which was unnecessary because those values have already been passed through `parseInt()`
- In the context of the `each()` function called from a `$()` DOM selector `this` provides the element in this iteration. So `LabourItems.init(this);` passes the actual element to `init` which is then used via `$(object)`

See http://jsfiddle.net/3TnyR/1/

Well, that's pretty much it!

Comment: what an answer my friend, this is great, your teaching me how to fish right now, if you understand my meaning.

Comment: actually on jsfiddle it works on keydown, but in my app 'rails' its only working on the first instance of labouritems and only when i'm tabbing out of the field. Could it be the structure of the div that holds the labouritems? also i'm dynamically adding the instances of labouritem fields into the form, not sure if that helps.